# Find the determinant of A

Tags: linear-algebra

find the determinant of A using **only** determinant properties

$$
    A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & -4   \\
    -2 & 1 & 2 \\
    -9 & 15 & 0  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Which determinant properties?

Comment: All of them, such as the one Ahmed Bazzi used

Comment: But the determinant properties include how to find the determinant.  It's not clear which methods you're disallowing.

Comment: none, I am disallowing none

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the third row is a linear combination of the first two, i.e. $r_3 = 6r_2 + 3r_1$, hence the determinant is $0$

Answer (score 4):

Row reduction does not change the determinant:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & -4 \\ -2 & 1 & 2 \\ -9 & 15 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & -4 \\ 0 & 7 & -6 \\ 0 & 42 & -36 \\ \end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & -4 \\ 0 & 7 & -6 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant is zero because the last matrix has a row of zeros.